# Google Maps V2 API Key Not Found (But it IS there)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, api-key

I'm trying to port an existing, working Google Maps App from API V1 to V2. 
I followed the directions on developers.google.com scrupulously but still no joy. The problem is that "API key not found" according to LogCat. The LogCat output is below:

```
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175): Caused by:ava.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found. Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>
                is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fb.a(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzk(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zztD(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2130)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5610)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
05-04 11:46:55.882: E/AndroidRuntime(15175):    ... 19 more
```

But it **is** there: My Manifest is below (API key is mutilated for this post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ramrod.GoogleMapV2"
  android:versionCode="100"
  android:versionName="1.00">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
/>
<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x0020000"
    android:required="true"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFU_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_GSERVICES"   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"   />

<application
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="GoogleMapV2"
  android:allowBackup="false">
  <activity android:name=".GoogleMapV2Main"
            android:label="GoogleMapV2">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
  />
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyC0T6B0VEcEALyQi3WXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  />
</application>
</manifest>
```

I've been beating my head against the wall for almost a week with no joy. I've searched StackOverflow and the web: lot's of people with API key problems but almost universally with syntax problems. Unless I've gone XML-blind, I don't think that's my problem.

Anybody see something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it could be the main reason but you have

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>
```

where the **V2** is with upper **V** and the logcat is saying to put it with lower **v**

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="AIzaSyC0T6B0VEcEALyQi3WXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

Comment: Yup. That did it. Good Eyeball.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of Keys, one for debug sessions and other to publish your apks.

For a Debug Keystore you can get the SHA1 value in Eclipse.

Accessing from the menu: Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build

Probably you are using the wrong SHA1 value.

Try to put the values directly in the manifest. Don't use @integer....

Comment: Thanks but no. I got 2 API keys from google, 1 release, 1 debug. Tried both - no joy. Triple checked values.

Comment: i change the post. please try